# cannot display images from a folder using php

Tags: php, html

I'm able to display individual images by referring them using `<img>` tag but I have so many images so it would take lot of effort to refer every image individually.

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'paintings/'; //image's     folder path

$num_files = glob($folder_path .     "*.{JPG,jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp}",     GLOB_BRACE);

$folder = opendir($folder_path);

if($num_files &gt; 0)
{
    while(false !== ($file =     readdir($folder))) 
{
        $file_path =     $folder_path.$file;
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'jpeg'|| $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp') 
    {
        ?&gt;
            &lt;a href="&lt;?php echo     $file_path; ?&gt;"&gt;&lt;img src="&lt;?php echo $file_path; ?&gt;"  height="250" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;?php
    }
}
}
else
{
echo "the folder was empty !";
}
closedir($folder);
?>
```

Comment: So your question is...? (Please also note that `glob()` returns an array with all your filepaths, not the number of files)

Comment: Here I placed all images in a folder and display all images from that folder using php can you suggest any example.?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It works.

Comment: I know code is perfect,but I just doesn't display images it display php ending tag and braces and semicolns and sometimes part of code.

Comment: OMG... Change all `&gt;` into `>` and all `&lt;` into `<`... (So all our edits was wrong! LOL)

Comment: Ohhh noo okay do you have any other script that would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, your code doesn't work because — for mysterious reason — you have changed all `<>` in `&lt;&gt;` (Maybe you have copied code from some web source?)

BTW, for the records: You use `glob()` to retrieve total file number and then `readdir()` to process each file.

You can directly process `glob()` result, improving performance of your code:

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'paintings/'; //image's     folder path
$files = glob($folder_path . "*.{JPG,jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

if( count( $files ) )
{
    foreach( $files as $file_path )
    {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="250" /></a>
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    echo "the folder was empty !";
}
?>
```

No need to check for extensions (with `glob()` you have only desired files).